# Intellij Project some files are not updating on compile

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am trying to compile an IntelliJ project, and have been working on it for over a month with no issues. Today I tried to compile and the changes I made in certain files did not make it into the compiled jar. As if by magic old versions of my code are being built, despite my attempts to completely remove any signs of the old code.

Somehow, refactoring the files to another name fixes it. This suddenly started happening today to multiple projects and I have no idea how to fix it. Help?

I've already tried manually deleting the cache for the application, and invalidating cache in the program itself.

No error messages, although I noticed that the files that refuse to change are blue in color, even after pushing to git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove .idea folder and .iml files. Then open the project from IntelliJ as below.

[image]